# Basic UNIX regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use the `re.match()` method to check if my string looks like the regular expression.

In UNIX on the cmd line I'd use `"*,*"` to check against a string such as, `hello,there`.

The following python doesn't work, what is there to change?

```
# line is just some string
if re.match(r'*,*', line):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

`*,*` on UNIX is not a regular expression. In regex, `*` means to take 0 or more of the preceding character. If you want to check if there is a comma between strings, you can do:

```
if re.match(r"\w+,\w+"):
    pass
```

`\w` specifies a word character, and `+` specifies one or more. So you are saying *I want a comma, between two words*.

Comment: Another option would be to point the OP at the [`fnmatch` standard-library Python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html), which *does* implement standard UNIX shell pattern matching.